# In a for loop, Println functions make loop cycles forever. Why does it happening?

Tags: java, for-loop, primes, println

I found some programming exercises but this one didn't solved. Program takes input as integer then sums the amount of prime number you give. Code is to fail I know but while I'm to trying to debug it fount something interesting if I run the commented println functions then loop takes forever and never terminate itself. Can someone explain why?

```
    static void problem11() {//summing prime numbers
    System.out.println("how many numbers do you want?");
    int aim = scanner.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    int datum = 2;
    int sum = 0;
    while(count<aim) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for(int i=datum-1; i>=2; i--) {
            **//System.out.println("inside for, datum: " + datum);**
            if(datum%i==0)
                **//System.out.println(datum +" is not a prime number");**
                prime = false;
        }
        if(prime) {
            System.out.println("one prime found");
            count++;
            sum += datum;
        }
        datum++;
    }
    System.out.printf("\nSum of first %d prime numbers is: %d", aim, sum);
}
```

Thanks to @Andy , @MauricePerry , and @Nevexis. Yes I know I should use curly brackets but I'm trying to shorten my code for readability but as a beginner I probably keep on the safe lane.

Comment: `for(int i=datum-1; i>=2; i--)` Can you explain what is happening here? *This is causing your problem.*

Comment: One other note - if you literally uncomment the 2nd println ("is not a prime...")  it would change the logic due to the lack of brace on if statement.

Comment: Works for me. Just don't forget the braces if you uncomment the println in the if.

Comment: @Andy To add on to that, this is one reason why you should use curly braces for loops and `if` statements even if it is only a single line _right now_.

Comment: This shows once more that you should always use braces in a compound statement.

Answer (score 0):

One other note - if you literally uncomment the 2nd println ("is not a prime...") it would change the logic due to the lack of brace on if statement. – Andy 4 hours ago 
Thanks for help this is the answer.